# How do I create a javax.json.JsonObject from a ambiguous hashmap?

Tags: java, json

I've currently got an ambiguous hashmap that contains `<String,Object>` pairs and would like to convert it into a `javax.json.JsonObject`.

I've only been able find `Json.createObjectBuilder()` as a means to create the `JsonObject` but not convert an existing map to one. Is there a utility that already exists that I can use to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Use GSon utility. You can download the jar from [here](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/g/Downloadgson222jar.htm)

And here is the [link](https://kodejava.org/how-do-i-convert-map-into-json/) to an example on how to use Gson to convert HashMap into Json String